# Can a team car ride ahead of the peloton to support a cyclist?

Tags: racing

Suppose someone is solo-ing or is part of a break-away group that is several minutes ahead of the peloton. And they get a flat tire. Is the team car allowed to ride ahead of the peloton to reach the person and fix the problem? Or does that person have to wait for the peloton, then the team car, and thus loose their position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally teams have two cars, and one is allowed to move forward to service the breakaway when the gap exceeds 30 seconds

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [Andy P's answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/57726/13174), there are also "neutral service" cars and motorbikes that carry spare wheels, parts and even whole bikes for riders who are distanced from their team cars. For example, [Chris Froome briefly used a neutral service bike](http://www.cyclist.co.uk/news/1464/why-was-froome-unable-to-use-neutral-service-bike) before running up Mount Ventoux.